# C# + database - Using a int as query from a column to retrieve row data

Tags: c#, wpf, database

So,

I have a calculated `int Answer` in my program.

In my database are six columns.
The columns are **ValueID, A, B, C, D** and **E.**

*When I press a button, I want the values from A, B, C, D and E where Answer matches ValueID, shown in a message box.*

What I am doing now (possibly stupid) is below:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Answer;
        if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            Answer = Grade3 + Addition + PTime;
        }
        else
        {
            Answer = Grade + Addition + PTime;
        }
        //MessageBox.Show("Answer is: " + Answer);

        int Value = Answer;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename =|DataDirectory|\dbiss.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
            con.Open();
            //SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT NC, Nodularity, UTS, Elongation, BHN FROM DataISS WHERE ValueID = '" + Value + "'", con);
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT NC, Nodularity, UTS, Elongation, BHN FROM " +
                             "DataISS WHERE ValueID = @value", con);

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", Value);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", reader["id"]));
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("'" + Value + "'", "con"); delete this line and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the proper way of adding parameters:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT NC, Nodularity, UTS, Elongation, BHN FROM " +
                                 "DataISS WHERE ValueID = @value", con);

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", Value);
```

One of the overloads of `AddWithValue` takes the parameter name in used in the query and the value for that parameter.

If you still don't get any results, you need to try the same query using Query Window in Visual studio. You can then identify the problem that might be in a wrong `Value` sent from the c# application or in the way you're calculating the `Value` local parameter that is used as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does the case difference between Value and @value matter?

Comment: I am not getting any output or error when doing this? What could be wrong? Any ideas.

Comment: @Dr.Viper It is preferred. But no, the API Already adds @ when executing if it is missing. But I recommend you keeping it for clarity. Execute the same query using SQL query window, do you get result ?

Comment: It returned error as "Wrong Syntax near +" when run in SQL query window.

But when I run this - SELECT NC, Nodularity, UTS, Elongation, BHN FROM DataISS WHERE ValueID = @value,

I get

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@value".

Comment: @Dr.Viper when executing in query window replace `@value` with 1, 2 or whatever the `ValueID` is that you're passing from c#.

Comment: Replacing valueID with "some value from database" gives me the results. YES. This means that SQL and Database are ok, right?

But the software is not showing any message.

Comment: @Dr.Viper are you sure the value of `Answer` is as you expect in your c# application ? It seems that it is not as expected. Debug your code and check what is the value of that local variable before executing the query.

Comment: With the minimal details I gave you, you correctly identified the issue. In the meantime, I sent a correct ValueID by using it in int ValueID = 2206063. It gave me the correct output. Now my struggle is in formatting the output.

There is a problem in the calculation as well. I am correcting it in the mean time. Thanks a million.

Comment: @Dr.Viper please mark this as an answer if you find it helpful. I added some info on how to identify the issue to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Structure command like below

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select NC, Nodularity, UTS, Elongation, BHN from DataISS where ValueID=@ValueID", con);
comm.Parameters.Add("@ValueID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Value;
```

Comment: Not getting any output or error. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: because you are getting only id in messageBox by using "reader["id"]"

Comment: Tried reader[0]. through reader[4],

Still nothing. The SQL query is returning scalar variable not declared error for @Value

Comment: Can you send type of table's each colums. e.g varchar, Int, bit?

Comment: As per user3185569 suggestion below "Replacing valueID with "some value from database" gives me the results. YES. This means that SQL and Database are ok, right? But the software is not showing any message."

The types are 

[ValueID]    INT        NULL,
    [NC]         INT        NULL,
    [Nodularity] FLOAT (53) NULL,
    [UTS]        INT        NULL,
    [Elongation] FLOAT (53) NULL,
    [BHN]        INT        NULL,

Comment: Understand the case. Becareful that you are sending the corresponding ID. If ID does not exist, you get an error

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks to all for their support, especially your input regarding the reader ID.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using "using" in your code, so it closes connection itself. For example:

```
  public static bool SomeMethod(int valueId)
    {
        bool result;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DataConnection.MailForm))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Mails
                                               WHERE ValueID= @valueId";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valueId", valueId);
                    int entryIdExist = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    result = entryIdExist <= 0;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Use "@" before your string, this way you can use as many rows without connecting them with +